# SQL Server update query error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '4'.
>
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

My code:

```
public partial class editemp : Window
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Haier;Initial Catalog=HRMS;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    int empid;

    public editemp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void editemp_fun(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        searchid(textBox.Text);
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee set EmpID='"+empid+ "',E_Name='" + textBox.Text + "',E_Contact='" + textBox_Copy.Text + "',Designaiton='" + textBox_Copy1.Text + "',Password='" + passwordBox.Password.ToString() + "Where EmpID='"+empid.ToString() +"'", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        new employees().Show();
        Close();
    }

    public void searchid(string name)
    {
        //con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee where E_Name='"+textBox.Text+"'",con);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            empid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
        }
    }

    private void cancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new employees().Show();
        Close();
    }
}
```

The main query that has to be focus is

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee set EmpID='"+empid+ "',E_Name='" + textBox.Text + "',E_Contact='" + textBox_Copy.Text + "',Designaiton='" + textBox_Copy1.Text + "',Password='" + passwordBox.Password.ToString() + "Where EmpID='"+empid.ToString() +"'", con);
```

in the where clause it is giving the error mentioned above.

Thank you very much

Comment: First thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead. That may well be *all* you need to do, but it should definitely be the *first* thing you do. See http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Give a 'quote' and 'space' before where keyword.

"' Where EmpID='"+empid.ToString()

Comment: Next, learn about the naming conventions for .NET, and follow them.

Comment: And you should NEVER store passwords in clear. Many people use only a few passwords for every account. This data should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Sir  @Akshay Mahajan thank you very much it was a space error,thanks alot

Comment: ok can you suggest me any tip for salting and hashing @SeanLange

Comment: Sure...google has a ton of suggestions. https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+salt+and+hash+passwords

Comment: You don't need to write your own salting/hasing code. .NET *already* provides this for web applications. Desktop applications can use this functionality too.

Comment: @ammadyouasf Please upvote the anwser if it worked for you so that others would prefer it

Answer (score -1):

There's a space missing before where, and also a single quote.

So

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee set EmpID='"+empid+ "',E_Name='" + textBox.Text + "',E_Contact='" + textBox_Copy.Text + "',Designaiton='" + textBox_Copy1.Text + "',Password='" + passwordBox.Password.ToString() + "' Where EmpID='"+empid.ToString() +"'", con);
```

However, I urge you to do what has been suggested by others in the comments. If not, you could still get errors depending on the values you are using to build the sql command text.

Comment: Sir you have suggest me the same point that @Akshay Mahajan suggest me,thank alot i have successfully run my query,Thank you again

Comment: It's similar. That comment is still missing the closing single quote before WHERE. It is the missing quote that is the problem - that's why the error is "Unclosed quotation mark" UPDATE - I can see there's a quote there now as well. Perhaps I missed it the first time or the comment was edited. Never mind, it's important you solved it, but please do what all the other comments suggest about improving your code. Best regards

Comment: sir i have provide that quotation mark thank you , now my query is same as yours, that you have mention here

Comment: well i know that i have to put that quotation mark but the problem was that i cannot identify that where is that mark is missing so when some point out that mark then i also observed that the quotation mark was missing too ,so i put the required mark there too ,thank you again for your precious time

Comment: i also rate your answer and i am concluding your provided query as my answer of this post

Comment: Posting an answer that continues to allow sql injection is not a good answer. It is only going to perpetuate horrible coding.

Comment: @SeanLange The guy asked about the error and I explained why the error happens, but I also pointed out that there are other issues addressed by other comments and that he should improve his code. There is so much wrong with that code that the only proper answer would've been "go learn to code", but that's a bit harsh, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps demonstrating how to use parameters would be a huge improvement. Sure there are still plenty of issues. The password in plain text, the command and connections not wrapped in USING statements. Perhaps my downvote is a bit harsh but without at least attempting to demonstrate some improvement with so much low hanging fruit I can't do anything else.

Answer (score -3):

the answer is

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee set EmpID='"+empid+ "',E_Name='" + textBox.Text + "',E_Contact='" + textBox_Copy.Text + "',Designaiton='" + textBox_Copy1.Text + "',Password='" + passwordBox.Password.ToString() + "' Where EmpID='"+empid.ToString() +"'", con);
```

thank you to Sir NemanjanPerovic and Akshay Mahajan

Comment: This is ***STILL WIDE OPEN*** to SQL injection attacks - this is ***NOT*** the answer ! Learn how to use **parametrized queries!** - right now!

Comment: NO this is awful. You need to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Google for Bobby Tables. And think what will happen if someone says his name is `Pwnd'; DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE;--` That's *exactly* what script kiddies do to hack web applications